# Rails Elasticsearch + Searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a problem with integrating searchkick and elasticsearch. Here is what I have as of now:

```
Product records:
id: 1
title: "Electric Fan"

id: 2
title: "Stove"

id: 3
title: "Stoven"

id: 4
title: "Stovener"
```

Here is my model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick
end
```

But when I go to the rails console and try to search it only gives me one result:

```
results = Product.search("Stove")
results.map(&:title) # prints ["Stove"]
```

I don't know why it is only generating one results which in fact it should generate three. I installed and made sure that elasticsearch is running.

Is there anything that I missed with this one?

TIA

Comment: Can you provide your mapping for that index?

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation:

> By default, results must match the entire word - back will not match backpack. You can change this behavior with:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick word_start: [:name]
end
```

And to search (after you reindex):

> Product.search "back", fields: [{name: :word_start}]

SOURCE - https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#partial-matches